# AutoFilter method of Range class failed - Array <> NOT EQUAL

Tags: arrays, vba, autofilter

I am in need for assistance. I am not an expert and I am learning VBA and I just need a piece of advice for a filter that I am trying to apply. The following code gives me an error:

> 'AutoFilter method of Range class failed'

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=Array("<>A", "<>B", "<>C"), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

However, when I run the same code with the EQUAL it gives no error.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=Array("=A", "=B", "=C"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try doing that manually in your sheet and you might see the problem.

Comment: When I tried manually, the macro recorder only uses equals. But I cannot make a list of all value. Instead, non-equals values are limited so easy to identify.

Comment: Alternatively, I was thinking to invert the selection after filtering it.
Any ideas?